# LibGdx - Error loading json file from asset manager

Tags: json, libgdx

I am loading a skin using the assetmanager and keep getting an error because `There is no Bitmapfont registered with name: font_dpb_59`. I am trying to use this font in my json-file to create a Label-style. 
I am adding fonts and atlas in the skins parameters, am I missing something here?

I load my skin like this:

```
        ObjectMap<String, Object> font_map = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
        font_map.put("font_dpb_59", font_dpb_59);
        font_map.put("font_dpm_40", font_dpm_40);
        //... some more fonts

        manager.load(skinAtlas, TextureAtlas.class);
        manager.load(menuSkin, Skin.class, new SkinLoader.SkinParameter(skinAtlas, font_map));
```

As you can see I add the fonts as parameters, but get an error. No idea what I'm doing wrong, the fonts are loaded before the skin.

Full stack trace:

```
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: menu_ui/ui_skin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:570)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:375)
    at com.scene2d.space_camp.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: menu_ui/ui_skin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:97)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.SkinLoader.loadSync(SkinLoader.java:75)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.SkinLoader.loadSync(SkinLoader.java:38)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:141)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:90)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:498)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:373)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: menu_ui/ui_skin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:694)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Serialization trace:
{}."com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle".font_dpb_59.font
font (com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:804)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:919)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:408)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:852)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.readNamedObjects(Skin.java:429)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:418)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:414)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:884)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:408)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:692)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont registered with name: font_dpb_59
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.get(Skin.java:149)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:407)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:797)
    ... 19 more
```

If this helps here is my json-file:

```
{
  "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color": {
    "white": {
      "r": 1, "g": 1, "b": 1, "a": 1
    }
  },

  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
    "font_dpb_59": {
      "font": "font_dpb_59", "fontColor": "white"
    }
  },

  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle": {
    "txt_btn_white": {
      "up": "button1",
      "down": "button1",
      "font": "font_dpb_59",
      "fontColor": "white",
      "pressedOffsetX": 1,
      "pressedOffsetY": -1 }
  },

  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle": {
    "btn_white": {
      "up": "button1" ,
      "down": "button1",
      "pressedOffsetX": 1,
      "pressedOffsetY": -1 }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle": {
    "default": { }
  },

  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle": {
    "default": { "titleFont": "font_dpb_59", "titleFontColor": "white" }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

This is how I load the fonts:

```
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
        manager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
        manager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

        FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter params59 = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
        params59.fontFileName = font_dpb_59;
        params59.fontParameters.size = 59;
        manager.load(font_dpb_59, BitmapFont.class, params59);
```

Comment: Not sure what might be the problem. Is it possible your font is not a BitmapFont object? If it's a subclass of BitmapFont, it won't get registered as a BitmapFont in the skin.

Comment: @Tenfour04 added code to show how I load the bitmapfont objects. Could it be that since all this is loaded at the same time (i.e I never call finishLoading), the fonts are not loaded before the skin? That would be a bit weird tho since I do load the fonts "before" the skin

Comment: How do you have a reference to the BitmapFont if you haven't finished loading it? I would say, yes, this is the problem. Actually, it looks suspicious that `font_dpb_59` is your fontFileName parameter since that's the name of the resource you put in the ObjectMap. Maybe you passed Strings to your SkinParameter instead of BitmapFonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects you pass into your ObjectMap here:

```
ObjectMap<String, Object> font_map = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
font_map.put("font_dpb_59", font_dpb_59);
font_map.put("font_dpm_40", font_dpm_40);
```

must be BitmapFont objects, not String paths. In order to have a BitmapFont instance, you must have already finished loading one. If you are using AssetManager to load them, you must call `finishLoading` on the asset manager, then `get(".....", BitmapFont.class)` to get the BitmapFont reference to put in your object map.

I had assumed you were doing this because you were creating BitmapFonts at runtime with FreeTypeFontGenerator, so there was no way to load them from Json. But if you already have the font files ahead of time, there's no reason you can't put them in your skin's Json file directly:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
    font_dpb_59: { file: path/to/font_dpb_59.fnt,
                   scaledSize: 12, //integer height of capital letters
                   markupEnabled: false,
                   flip : false},
}
```

Comment: Oh really? I just thought that would kind of interfere with the AssetManager somehow. So I don't really need to load the fonts using assetManager at all then? I can just add the directly to the skin, and when I dispose the skin I dispose the fonts automatically? But then I can't set the size of the font like I do above using parameters.

Comment: I tried to make a seperate methods for loading fonts and made sure it finished loading before the other stuff started, and now it work perfectly. Thank you :D This is important for me since I need to set the font size

Comment: You actually can set some parameters on the font. See update above. `scaledSize` is how many integer pixels tall a capital letter is, so it's not exactly the same as scale.

Comment: Awesome! Going to try this out tomorrow! Thanks for all your help buddy!